# how to I wipe NSCoder data so it's not available at next App start?

Tags: ios, state-restoration

For an iOS app I don't want the app to use some restoration data after a user logs out. Ideally, I'd like to wipe the data at the point the user logs out.

What is the pattern for adding this to standard `encodeRestorableState()/decodeRestorableState()` handling?